# Template friend function of template class that introduces a new template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, friend

Thanks to Daniel Frey's answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18792565/declare-template-friend-function-of-template-class), I know how to declare a template friend function to a template class with the same template parameters. Unfortunately, the syntax for declaring a friend function with additional template parameters still escapes me. I would like to achieve something like this:

```
template <typename T>
class Obj;

template <typename T>
Obj<T> make_obj(T t);

template <typename T, typename RetVal>
RetVal ret_obj(T t);

template <typename T>
class Obj {
private:
    T & t;
    Obj (T & t) : t(t) { }
    Obj() = delete;

    friend Obj make_obj<T>(T t);

    template <typename RetVal>
        friend RetVal ret_obj<T, RetVal>(T t);
};

template <typename T>
Obj<T> make_obj(T t) { 
    return Obj<T>(t);
}

template <typename T, typename RetVal>
RetVal ret_obj(T t) {
    return RetVal(make_obj(t).t);
}
```

I know that the same question has already been asked in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16923087/friend-template-function-of-a-template-class), but the accepted answer there does not seem to be what I want: changing the parameter name to `T2` makes the function a friend of all specializations of the object, while I want to keep `T` the same as in the class.

Comment: As a guess, I'd say "you can't".  There are going to be workarounds that will make it work, like say bouncing the function through a helper `struct`.

Comment: Not possible. Friend declarations cannot declare partial specializations.

Comment: @Yakk Yeah I figured I could use another class, and will, if I have to; I was just wondering if there was a direct way to do this. Too bad if not. :(

Comment: @T.C. and there are no partial specializations of functions regardless.  Hmm: can you make a using alias a friend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible to let `friend` declarations refer to partial specializations - either they refer to a specific specialization or to the primary template. Moreover, function templates cannot be partially specialized anyway.
What is not possible with function templates is often doable using class templates though:

```
template <typename T>
struct ret_obj_helper {
    // Here goes the original definition of ret_obj - the important difference
    // is the location of the template parameter T, which is the one
    // fixed by the friend declaration below
    template <typename RetVal>
    RetVal ret_obj(T t) {return RetVal(make_obj(t).t);}
};

// I guess RetVal, having to be explicitly specified, better goes first (?)
template <typename RetVal, typename T>
RetVal ret_obj(T&& t)
{
    // Overcomplicated for the sake of perfect forwarding
    return ret_obj_helper<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>{}.
      template ret_obj<RetVal>(std::forward<T>(t));
}

template <typename T>
class Obj {
private:
    T t;
    Obj (T t) : t(t) { }
    Obj() = delete;

    friend Obj make_obj<T>(T t);

    // Make all specializations of the member function template 
    // of ret_obj_helper<T> a friend, regardless of the return type
    template <typename RetVal>
    friend RetVal ret_obj_helper<T>::ret_obj(T t);
};
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3ea6a18322f80f8a).

Comment: Yeah, I knew it will boil down to this after reading the comments above. Just a question though: if the reference is not removed, calling the function with one would not compile?

Comment: What is the benefit of using a public struct, instead of a public static member? I can see no difference in the degree of encapsulation. Since the public function cannot be a friend, it has to go through an ugly public interface.