# Additional template arguments for friend declaration in template class?

Tags: c++, templates, friend

In order for some global function

```
template<typename T, int count>
void func (const Obj<T>& obj) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        std::cout << obj.value << std::endl;
}
```

to be able to access to the private field `value` of some templated class

```
template<typename T>
class Obj {
    public:
        Obj (T value);
    private:
        T value;
};

template<typename T>
Obj<T>::Obj (T value) : value(value) {}
```

we need to declare `func<T, count>` a friend of `Obj<T>`. But `func<T, count>` has to be declared before we can make it a friend of `Obj<T>`, and for this we need to forward-declare `Obj<T>`. The resulting code looks like this

```
// Forward declarations
template<typename T>
class Obj;

template<typename T, int count>
void func (const Obj<T>& obj);

// Obj<T>
template<typename T>
class Obj {
    public:
        Obj (T value);

        template<int count>
        friend void func<T, count> (const Obj<T>& obj);
    private:
        T value;
};

template<typename T>
Obj<T>::Obj (T value) : value(value) {} // <-- ERROR

// func<T>
template<typename T, int count>
void func (const Obj<T>& obj) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        std::cout << obj.value << std::endl;
}
```

But this makes gcc complain about the "invalid use of template-id 'func' in declaration of primary template", so how do I actually declare `func<T, count>` a friend of `Obj<T>` for every `count`? According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16923220/2668681) I just need to replace the friend declaration with this

```
template<typename T1, int count>
friend void func (const Obj<T1>& obj);
```

As far as I know this would make `func<T1, count>` a friend of `Obj<T>` regardless of whether `T1` and `T` match, which is absurd. Is it possible to declare `func<T, count>` a friend of `Obj<T>` and no other `Obj<T1>`? (preferably in a way that keeps the definition of `func<T, count>` outside the definition of `Obj<T>`)

(I know I could just make `count` a real parameter, but the example above is just a simplification of my real code. In reality I'm trying to overload `std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& operator<< (std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& stream, const Obj<T>& obj)` for some class `Obj<T>` in a way that allows `operator<<` to access private fields of `Obj<T>`.)

Comment: You don't need any of the two forward declarations you have (the class `Obj` or the function `func`). Instead the `friend` declaration of the function will act as a forward declaration on its own.

Comment: Can't you just define the function in the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `friend` declaration must match any possible forward declaration, and of course the definition, including template arguments.

That means you need e.g.

```
template<typename U, int count>
friend void func(const Obj<U>& obj);
```

It doesn't matter if the class template argument `T` and the function template argument `U` are different, as the calls will be made to the correct function anyway.

Example:

```
Obj<int> int_obj;
Obj<float> float_obj;

func<X>(int_obj);  // Will call void func<int, X>(int_obj)
func<X>(float_obj);  // Will call void func<float, X>(float_obj)
```

---

As an alternative, you can *define* the function inline in the class definition, and then you don't need to provide the `T` or `U` template arguments:

```
template<int count>
friend void func(const Obj<T>& obj)
{
    // Implementation...
}
```

And in neither case you should really have a forward declaration of `func` (as mentioned in my comment).

Comment: But how do you ensure that `func<U, count>` is not a friend of `Obj<T>`, if `T` and `U` do not match? To me this seems to declare `func<std::string, 5>` a friend of `Obj<int>` or am I wrong?

Comment: And how would this work with `std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& operator<< (std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& stream, const Obj<T>& obj)`?

Comment: @Cubi73 If `U` is `std::string` then the declaration becomes `friend void func(const Obj<std::string>& obj);`. Yes it will be a friend of e.g. `Obj<int>` but you can't pass an `Obj<int>` object to the function, so does it really matter?

Comment: Yes, it does matter. If I can make `func(Obj<T> obj)` a friend of only `Obj<T>` when just omitting the additional `count` argument, there should be a way to do the same when including the `count` argument.